# How to set the caret position in a contenteditable div in Firefox and old IE versions

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to set the caret position in a contenteditable div. Here is code that works in modern IE, Chrome and Safari, but does not work in Firefox 36.0.4 or old IE versions (9 or less). For this answer it is safe to assume that the contenteditable div contains only text (i.e no child elements other than a single text node).

Please tell me how to fix this, especially for Firefox.

Thank you.

HTML:

```
<div contenteditable id="d">12345</div>
<div contenteditable id="log"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function moveCaret(d, position) {
    d.focus(); // This is included because in my application the div is already focused by the time the caret must be moved.
    if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(d.childNodes[0], position);
        range.setEnd(d.childNodes[0], position);
        sel.addRange(range);
        d.focus();
     } else if (document.selection && document.body.createTextRange) {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(d);
        textRange.select();
        d.focus();
    }
}

try {
    var position = 0;
    var d = document.getElementById("d");
    moveCaret(d, 3);
}catch(e) {
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += e.toString();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bk7ade2r/

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that firefox can not focus() on a contenteditable div.